# Twilio Real Time Recording

Tags: node.js, real-time, twilio

I am using Twilio voice call
and
want to get the voice data of other person(in voice call) at REAL TIME. So that i can convert it into text etc.

Please let me know how to achieve this.

I know twilio has a record call feature but
1) It gives url at the end of call not at real time
2) i think it will record the whole conversation (of both persons)

I am thinking of using node.js but not able to find solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm afraid our [programmable voice](https://www.twilio.com/voice) feature doesn't support streaming the audio in real time in any way other than between the callers.

You can, however, [use SIP with Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/sip). You would need to [provide your own PBX](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/sip-trunking/sample-configuration) to make this work, but it then gives you access to the streaming audio, which you can then work with yourself.

Let me know if this helps at all?

Comment: If i  use node.js + twillio and write some of my code in node.js to detect the received audio from twilio by using some event handler etc.

Will it work as the environment will be same i.e node.js?

Is there any similar or different way to achieve my requirement?

Comment: Hello Phil, does this limitation still hold, or is it possible to set up a Twilio-only system (using e.g. conferencing) that would allow access to voice recording in real time?

Comment: @dpq It's still not a feature of Twilio to allow real time access to the audio stream. One suggestion is to set up a conference that your two parties dial into, plus a third leg that is dialled into from your own server and can listen to the call.